# Trying to create a diffie-hellman pem file with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, fips, dovecot

This is my first time posting a question. I’m trying to generate a diffie-hellman pem file for dovecot email on a RHEL8 machine and I’m receiving an error from OpenSSL.

My machine is:
RHEL8.4 4.18.0-305.7.1.el8_4.x86_64

Command:
Openssl dhparam –out /etc/dovecot/dh.pem 4096

Error:
139926454208320:error:050C90CA:Diffie-Hellman routines:DH_generate_parameters_ex:non FIPS method:crypto/dh/dh_gen.c:31:

I haven’t found much help on the web. I figure it’s related to FIPS being enabled but I can’t find a way around it.

Openssl version 1.1.1g release 15.el8_3

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, RedHat seems to have gone FIPS140 pretty hard, and this restriction appears due to SP800-56Arev3 which requires either the Oakley/IKEv2 (and SSH) groups from RFC3526 or similar TLS groups from RFC7919 except that for strength 112 _only_ groups generated per FIPS186-4 with p size 2048 (and q size 256 or 224) are grudgingly allowed for backward compatibility. (Both 140-2 and 140-3 IGs confirm this, in D.1-rev3 and D.F respectively.) You could try `openssl dsaparam 2048 | openssl dhparam -dsaparam`. Alternatively, why not just follow the IETF _and_ NIST recommendation?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That worked!!!! I ran "openssl dsaparam 2048 | openssl dhparam -dsaparam -out /etc/dovecot/dh.pem" and it worked. Apparently you can only use  a key length of 2048 or you will get a key length error if 4096 is used. But your method works with FIPS enabled.... Thanks a lot.